# Need help with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

The following is a simplified version of a database table I'm querying (let's call it Payments):

```
date     |    userid   |    payment
20/1/10  |      1      |      10
21/1/10  |      1      |      15
17/1/10  |      2      |      7
18/1/10  |      2      |      9
```

It records payments made by users on certain dates. I need to find out the details of the first payment made by each user like so:

```
20/1/10  |      1      |      10
17/1/10  |      2      |      7
```

Stored procedures are out of the question. Is there any way to do this using SQL alone or should I just add a first payment flag to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Payments
INNER JOIN (SELECT Min([Date]) AS MinDate, UserID 
            FROM Payments GROUP BY UserID) AS M
ON M.MinDate = Payments.Date AND M.UserID = Payments.UserID
```

Comment: Had to make a small correction, but all in all this works as expected

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT MIN([Date]), userid, payment
FROM Payments
GROUP BY Userid, payment
```

Comment: Doesn't actually work. I don't think you should be grouping by payment as well

Comment: ...except you have to group by payment since  you have an aggregate function.  Every column needs to be either a part of an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MIN([Date]), UserID FROM Payments GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: @Matthew Jones - +1 then :)  Bear in mind from his desired results he also wants to see the payment amount

Comment: @JNK I didn't get that from reading his question: *I need to find out the **dates** of the first payment made by each user*

Comment: @Matthew Jones - I'm basing that on his example output

Comment: I do want to see the payment amount. Question edited for clarity.